# What is the correct way to unify a page so it prints the same on all browsers?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a contract in HTML and I am having a lot of problems with printing. I can't get the font sizes to be anywhere close to the same between the newest version of Chrome and IE 9.

Chrome's fonts are big and the spacing between characters are unpredictable (sometimes really close together, sometimes far apart).

IE's font looks better but it's spacing between characters are really close and it is causing the page to be too short.

Is there a way to "synchronize" the printing between different browsers? Or at least get them close? Are there best practices when doing something like this?

Here is a scan of what the print difference looks like. The print preview looks fine but once it's printed the text on Chrome is really close together (or spread apart such as the word Drawings).

[image]

Comment: Have you looked into a CSS reset?

Comment: Have you considered a PDF as an alternative?

Comment: Definitely start with CSS reset

Comment: I find printing to still be unpredictable. But to ask the regular questions, have you declared a doctype? Ensured your markup and CSS are valid? Ensured fonts and sizes are specified so that the browser doesn't try to make guesses? And to echo others, CSS reset would definitely be helpful.

Comment: I have css reset. I am using the Arial font since that is what was originally used on the contract. I will scan a copy of Chrome & IE so you can see the difference and edit my original post.

Comment: Browsers don't even render stuff the same way. You can't expect that adding third-party printer drivers to the equation makes it better. Everyone who needs decent printer generates PDF files. Seriously.

Comment: I could generate a PDF but I am trying to get away from making the users download the contract (depending on their browser) and just view it in the browser. If I need to change fonts, then that is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the letter spacing is a known Chrome bug

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=72017

I submitted my findings there.